# Launching a jQuery Event from a Plugin on Checkbox Change

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox

I have the following code:

```
      <script>
        $('#switch-1:checkbox').change(function() {
if (this.checked) {
      $('#generatepassword').pGenerator({'uppercase': true});
} else {
      $('#generatepassword').pGenerator({'uppercase': false});
}
};
      </script>
```

When my checkbox is checked or unchecked, I want it to change the parameters of a plugin, whose goal is to generate a password. In this case I'm trying to set the parameter to uppercase FALSE or true depending if the checkbox is checked or not.

How do I write the code so that it sends the parameters to the plugin upon the event of the checkbox click?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#switch-1').click(function() {
if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    $('#generatepassword').pGenerator({'uppercase': true});
} else {
    $('#generatepassword').pGenerator({'uppercase': false});
}
};
```

Comment: I tried this, but all this code just shows up on my page. Any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Did you put it between your <script> tags?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. But the plugin still generates upper case letters when the checkbox is set to off. So I'm assuming it didn't work still, for some reason.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: Password Generator, found here:
https://accountspassword.com/password-generator-jquery-plugin

Comment: Look at the source.  Once checked the value is uppercase, setting uppercase to false just skips making the value upper case it doesn't restore the value.  You could set the lowercase option to true upon unchecking or if you want to restore to original value store the original value in a variable and restore upon unchecking.

Comment: I've tried
    $('#switch-1').click(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        $('#generatepassword').pGenerator({'uppercase': true});
    } else {
        $('#generatepassword').pGenerator({'lowercase': true});
    }
    };
But this didn't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of what you have?